# Instalar un modulo en Drupal 8 usando composer

Tags: php, composer, drupal, drupal8

Quiero instalar un modulo nuevo en Drupal 8, pero el cliente grafico me causa algunos errores por alguna razón. Quisiera usar mejor la terminal pues me parece más rapido y ya pude instalar un modulo oficial pero quiero instalar otro que es "externo".

Instale Geofield de la siguiente forma:

```
composer require drupal/geofield
```

Ahora quisiera instalar este otro: https://www.drupal.org/project/geolocation

pero no se la manera de hacerlo, alguien sabe como tendría que hacer mi petición?

busco algo como:

```
composer require https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/geolocation-8.x-3.0-rc1.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 1):

Para **descargar** módulos de Drupal usando composer: "composer require drupal/{module_name}":

```
composer require drupal/geolocation
```

Para **quitar** módulos de Drupal usando composer (asegúrate que están desinstalados): "composer remove drupal/{module_name}":

```
composer remove drupal/geolocation
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar la siguiente linea y así tienes en cuenta la versión del módulo, tal como lo quieres hacer en tu pregunta.

```
composer require 'drupal/geolocation:^3.0'
```

Es recomendable el uso de las comillas, incluso es requerido para la shell de Windows.

Comment: Hola José Abraham, aunque esta respuesta puede servir para resolver el problema expuesto en la pregunta, ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por la comunidad. Por favor, añade algo más de información para completar la publicación: ¿hay diferencia entre usar comillas o no? (como en la otra respuesta) ¿el número de versión es obligatorio? Lee [answer] donde encontrarás recomendaciones para mejorar tus respuestas. Un saludo.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por tu sugerencia, he editado la respuesta teniendo en cuenta lo que me comenta.